# WEB SQL select convert issue

Tags: sql, sqlite, web

Trying to covert a datetime into short date i.e. `19/09/2014` instead of `Wed Sep 19 2014 09:20:30 GMT+0100` (GMT Daylight Time).

I tried this

```
tx.executeSql("select strftime('%d/%m/%Y') added_on, sunum,......");
```

puts it into the correct format I want but puts it into today's date i.e. 17/09/2014

Then I tried :

```
tx.executeSql(" select convert(varchar(10), added_on, 110) sunum,......");
```

and I get an error: "could not prepare statement (1 no such function: varchar)"

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: `strftime()` is a SQLite function.  `convert()` with a format is a SQL Server construct.  What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a sqllite expert, or even a novice, but could you try this:

```
tx.executeSql("select strftime('%d/%m/%Y', added_on), added_on, sunum,......");
```

I found this [resource](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), but you likely already know about it.